# Best way to implement Entity with translatable properties in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Consider the following class (simplified in order to focus in the core problem):

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual string QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual string Hint { get; set; }
}
```

and tables:

```
Question
- QuestionId ((primary key, identity column and key)
- Code

QuestionTranslation
- QuestionTranslationId (primary key, identity column; not really relevant to the association)
- QuestionId (composite key element 1)
- CultureName (composite key element 2) (sample value: en-US, en-CA, es-ES)
- Text
- Hint
```

How I can map the Question class so the Text and Hint properties are populated using the current thread's culture. If the thread's culture is changed I would like the Text and Hint properties to automatically return the appropriate value without the need for the Question entity to be reloaded.

Note that I'm only outlining the relevant class and properties from the business side. I'm totally open to any new class or property needed to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: is making `(QuestionId, CultureName)` a compositeId an option? you could also leave `CultureName` out of the answer because accessing the primary key of question doesnt trigger lazy loading

Comment: @Firo: Making a composite key can be an option. Can you elaborate your response? Thanks.

Comment: Is the database read only or should it be updated as well?

Comment: @Stefan: In the public application most of the entities are read-only but in the admin application are read-write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect changed answer:

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual string QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text
    {
        get
        {
            var currentculture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            return Translations
                .Where(trans => trans.CultureName == currentculture)
                .Select(trans => trans.Text)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            var currentculture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            var translation = Translations
                .Where(trans => trans.CultureName == currentculture)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (translation == null)
            {
                translation = new QuestionTranslation();
                Translations.Add(translation);
            }
            translation.Text = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual string Hint
    {
        get
        {
            var currentculture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            return Translations
                .Where(trans => trans.CultureName == currentculture)
                .Select(trans => trans.Hint)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            var currentculture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            var translation = Translations
                .Where(trans => trans.CultureName == currentculture)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (translation == null)
            {
                translation = new QuestionTranslation();
                Translations.Add(translation);
            }
            translation.Hint = value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual ICollection<QuestionTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

class QuestionTranslation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string CultureName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string Hint { get; set; }
}

<class name="Question" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="QuestionId" column="QuestionId"/>

  <bag name="Translations" table="QuestionTranslation" lazy="true">
    <key>
      <column name="QuestionId"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="QuestionTranslation"/>
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="QuestionTranslation" table="QuestionTranslation" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="QuestionTranslationId"/>
  <many-to-one name="ParentQuestion" column="QuestionId"/>
</class>
```

if you have a lot of translations then change `ICollection<QuestionTranslation> Translations { get; set; }` to `IDictionary<string, QuestionTranslation> Translations { get; set; }` and map as `<map>` but normally the above should do it

Comment: I have rewritten the question so better explain my problem because I felt I was not clear when I wrote the question. Do you mind reviewing the question and modifying your response accordingly?

Comment: I've used your answer as start point for my own solution. I'm not sure the mappings will handle inserting/updating translations, for example there is no mapping for the QuestionTranslationId column on the translation table.

Comment: there is a typo `<id name="AnswerId"/>` should be `<id name="QuestionTranslationId"/>` and QuestionTranslation is missing the Id Property.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Firo's answer (yes, I copied it and adapted it and feel bad about this).

It uses a dictionary and maps the translations as composite element (so it doesn't need the id at all)

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual string QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text
    {
        get
        {
            var translation = Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name];
            if (translation != null) return translation.Text
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            GetTranslation(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Text = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string Hint
    {
        get
        {
            var translation = Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name];
            if (translation != null) return translation.Hint
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            GetTranslation(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Hint = value;
        }
    }


    private QuestionTranslation GetTranslation(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
    {
        QuestionTranslation translation;
        if (!Translations.TryGetValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out translation))
        {
           translation = new QuestionTranslation()
           Translations[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name] = translation;
        }
        return translation;
    }

    protected virtual IDictionary<string, QuestionTranslation> Translations { get; private set; }
}

class QuestionTranslation
{
    // no id, culture name
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual string Hint { get; set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
<class name="Question">
  <id name="QuestionId" column="QuestionId"/>

  <map name="Translations" table="QuestionTranslation" lazy="true">
    <key column="QuestionId"/>
    <index column="CultureName"/>
    <composite-element class="QuestionTranslation">
      <property name="Text"/>
      <property name="Hint"/>
    </composite-element>
  </bag>
</class>
```